# Result should be 11 after incrementing, it is 12, why?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{    
    int n, *p1, *p2;
    n = 10;
    p1 = &n; 
    p2 = p1;
    (*p1)++;
    (*p2)++;
    cout << *p1 << " " << *p2 << " "<< n << endl ;      
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: This is a perfect code to learn how to use a debugger. Debugger is really useful to find bug, _but_ also to learn programming ;). You can run your code step by step and so you can view evolution of your variables at each line of your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*p1` refers to the value pointed by the pointer `p1`. `(*p1)++` will increment the value of `n` by 1 and `(*p2)++` will again do the increment on n, since it is pointing to the same location of `p1`. So the n will be incremented to 12. `*p1`,`*p2` and `n` will thus have 12. So it prints 12.